# Solving an equation to find a function

Tags: analysis

I am trying to solve the following equation and find a real-valued function $y\left(x\right)$ which satisfies

$$
\exp{y\left(x\right)} + y\left(x\right) + 1 = 0, \hspace{0.2cm}\forall x>0
$$

Any ideas?

Comment: How does this relate to statistics? Please give more info ?